SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Best Practices for Using Sequelize ORM in Node.js Application
I’m using Sequelize ORM in my Node.js application, and I’m encountering an issue where I sometimes get a SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError. I’d like to get feedback on whether my approach is sound or if there’s something I’m doing wrong.
My Setup
I’ve configured Sequelize in a separate file called db.config.js:
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  process.env.DB_PASS,
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    pool: {
      max: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_MAX) || 5, // max connections in the pool
      min: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_MIN) || 0, // min connections in the pool
      acquire: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_ACQUIRE) || 30000, // max time (ms) to acquire a connection before throwing an error
      idle: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_IDLE) || 10000 // max time (ms) a connection can be idle before being released
    },
    logging: false
  }
);

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    logger.info('Database connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

module.exports = sequelize;

Here’s how I define my models:
const sequelize = require("../../config/db.config")

const Organization = sequelize.define(
  "Organization",
  {
    org_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT(1),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "Organizations"
  }
);

module.exports = {
  Organization,
};

In my application, I use the Sequelize instance like this:
const sequelize = require('../../../config/db.config');

const { Organization } = require('../../../models/tables/organization.model');

// I sometimes use transactional queries, so I create the transaction here
const dbTxn = await sequelize.transaction();

// Non-transactional read query
const existingOrganization = await Organization.findOne({
    where: {
        uuid: org_uuid,
        status: 1
    }
});

For transactional queries, I do something like this:
const result = await Organization.create(
  {
    org_name,
    uuid,
    status
  },
  { transaction: dbTxn }
);

I ensure that I commit and release transactions properly. However, even with this setup, I occasionally encounter the SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError. My goal is to use the same Sequelize instance throughout the application, which I believe is a good practice.

Is my approach correct?
What might be causing the SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError despite this setup?
Are there any best practices I should consider to avoid this issue?

